# Not receiving INTERNAL TEST releases immediately

Tags: android, google-play-console

Currently having internal tests on the applications and it takes about 1-2Hrs for it to reflect on the playstore, is this normal behaviour or am i doing something wrong, or missing something thing, does google mean 2 hrs by "immediate" ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes.it will take **more than one hour** to reflect those changes in playstore.it is the normal process.

Comment: if you can see in the screenshot, they have mentioned that "it will be available within few minutes", that's the reason i am concerned

Comment: yes.if you are testing the app internally,it will reflect within sometime for those whom you have shared test link but to reflect it in playstore,it will take more time.

Comment: so, as soon as i upload another version of test build, i should send the app link to all the testers who have already opted in?

Comment: yes.you should and it will take some time to reflect in playstore

Answer (score 0):

Internal testing track should make the download available within 1-2 minutes. On open and closed tracks it will take a couple of hours. Make sure you are using the right type of track: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: it took about 45 minutes to reflect on playstore, i am doing it on internal test track.

Comment: are you able to get internal tests app in 1-2 minutes ?

Comment: I would reach out to the Play Developer support. If this reproduces regularly, there may be a bug: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en